# Let $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is cts with $f(a), f(b) < 0, \int_a^b f(x)dx \ge 0$. Show $\exists c \in (a,b) s.t. \int_c^b f(t) dt \ge 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity

My solution to this problem is the following:

**Solution:**
$[a,b]$ is closed interval, so $f$ is uniformly continuous on the interval $[a,b]$.  So, we know that there exists $\delta >0$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, if $|x-c| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$.
In the above definition of uniform continuity, let $x=b$ and $c>b-\delta$, and notice that $x-c<\delta$.  Then applying the definition of continuity, we see that this implies $|f(b) - f(b-\delta)| < \epsilon$.
Expanding this inequality we see that we have $-\epsilon < f(b) - f(b-\delta) < \epsilon$.  Since this is true for any $\epsilon > 0$, then we can choose $\epsilon >0$ as we wish.
Choose $\epsilon < -f(b)$, and since $f(b) < 0$, then this means we still have $\epsilon > 0$.  Notice this implies that for all points $x_0$ in the domain strictly between $x$ and $c$, we have $f(x_0) < 0$.

Then observe that in the definition of integral, we have $\int_{c=b-\delta}^{b} f(x) dx = \inf\{U(P,f,\alpha): P\}.$
And since by definition $U = \sum_{i=1}^n M_{f_i}  \Delta \alpha_i$.

Then obviously since $f(x_0) < 0$ for all $x_0$ in this summation, then $\int_{c=b-\delta}^{b} f(x) dx < 0$.

I have a few questions about this solution:

1)  Is uniform continuity necessary?  Or is just continuity sufficient and if so, why?

2)  Is there an easier way to prove this than going to the definition of a Riemann integral as a sum?

Comment: You should write, at the beginning of your post : so we know that for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that ...

Comment: Have you thought of a scenario where $f$ is constant (negative)?

Comment: I have not considered that

Comment: @Adren, can you please tell me how that would help?

Comment: For any $c \in (a,b)$ we have $\int_a^c f + \int_c^b f= \int_a^b f \geqslant 0$, so $\int_c^bf \geqslant - \int_a^c f$. Now use continuity to show there exists $c$ such that that $f(x) \leqslant 0$ for all $x \in [a,c]$. What does that tell you about $-\int_a^c$?

Comment: well @RRL obviously that would mean that the integral $\int_a^c$ would be negative and hence $-\int_a^c$ would be positive.  but I don't see how that helps us show that $\int_c^b < 0$.  Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could critique my existing solution tha I put in the question.

Comment: Error: you wrote  $\int_c^b f < 0$ in your comment.